# Wanted but not invoke: Mockito PrintWriter

Tags: java, mockito, junit4, printwriter, powermockito

Hi I am working on a project and using `PrintWriter` class for opening and writing in the file. But when I am writing the test case for same it gives following error **at Line 153**

```
Wanted but not invoked:
  mockPrintWriter.println("ID    url1
  ");
 -> at x.y.z.verify(ProcessImageDataTest.java:153)
 Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.
```

Code: (Uses Lombok Library)

ProcessImageData.java

```
@Setter
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ProcessImageData implements T {
    private final File newImageDataTextFile;

   @Override
    public void execute() {
       LineIterator inputFileIterator = null;
       try {
        File filteredImageDataTextFile = new File(filteredImageDataTextFilepath);

          PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(newImageDataTextFile);
          inputFileIterator = FileUtils.lineIterator(filteredImageDataTextFile, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.displayName());
          while (inputFileIterator.hasNext()) {
                    if(someCondition)
           **Line51**           writer.println(imageDataFileLine);
                    //FileUtils.writeStringToFile(newImageDataTextFile, imageDataFileLine + NEWLINE, true);
                }
            }          

      } catch (Exception e) {

      } finally {
          LineIterator.closeQuietly(inputFileIterator);
 **LINE63**         writer.close();
      }
  }
```

ProcessImageDataTest.java

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({ ProcessImageData.class, FileUtils.class, Printwriter.class })
public class ProcessImageDataTest {

private ProcessImageData processImageData;

private static final String FILTERED_IMAGE_DATA_TEXT_FILE_PATH = "filteredFilepath";
private File FILTEREDFILE = new File(FILTERED_PATH);
private static final File IMAGE__FILE = new File("imageFilePath");

private LineIterator lineIterator;
@Mock
private PrintWriter mockPrintWriter;

@Before
public void init() throws Exception {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

    processImageData = new ProcessImageData(Palettes_file, FILTERED_PATH, IMAGE_FILE);

    PowerMockito.mockStatic(FileUtils.class);
    PowerMockito.whenNew(PrintWriter.class).withArguments(IMAGE_FILE).thenReturn(mockPrintWriter);

    PowerMockito.when(FileUtils.lineIterator(FILTERED_FILE, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.displayName())).thenReturn(lineIterator);
    PowerMockito.when(lineIterator.hasNext()).thenReturn(true, true, false);

}

@Test
public void testTaskWhenIDInDBAndStale() throws IOException {
    PowerMockito.when(lineIterator.nextLine()).thenReturn(ID2 + SPACE + URL1, ID1 + SPACE + URL2);

    processImageData.execute();

    List<String> exepctedFileContentOutput = Arrays.asList(ID2 + SPACE + URL1 + NEWLINE);
    verify(exepctedFileContentOutput, 1, 1);
}


@Test
public void testTaskWhenIDNotInDB() throws IOException {
    PowerMockito.when(lineIterator.nextLine()).thenReturn(ID2 + SPACE + URL1, ID3 + SPACE + URL2);

    processImageData.execute();

    List<String> exepctedFileContentOutput = Arrays.asList(ID3 + SPACE + URL2 + NEWLINE);
    verify(exepctedFileContentOutput, 1, 1);
}

private void verify(List<String> exepctedFileContentOutput, int fileWriteTimes, int fileReadTimes) throws IOException {
    for (String line : exepctedFileContentOutput){
**Line153**                     Mockito.verify(mockPrintWriter,  Mockito.times(fileWriteTimes)).print(line);  
    }

    PowerMockito.verifyStatic(Mockito.times(fileReadTimes));
    FileUtils.lineIterator(FILTERED_IMAGE_DATA_TEXT_FILE, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.displayName());
}

}
```

I am mocking a new operator for `PrintWriter` also, injecting using beans. What is the mistake I am doing?? I am stuck on it from long time and not getting the error? 
Any help is appreciated.

**Updated** :

I did changes suggested below and updated the code, but now I get the error:

```
Wanted but not invoked: mockPrintWriter.print("ASIN2 url1 "); -> 
at softlines.ctl.ruleExecutor.tasks.ProcessImageDataTest.verify‌​(ProcessImageDataTes‌​t.java:153) 
However, there were other interactions with this mock: -> at softlines.ctl.ruleExecutor.tasks.ProcessImageData.execute(Pr‌​ocessImageData.java:‌​51) ->  
at  softlines.ctl.ruleExecutor.tasks.ProcessImageData.execute(Pr‌​ocessImageData.java:‌​51) -> 
at softlines.ctl.ruleExecutor.tasks.ProcessImageData.execute(Pr‌​ocessImageData.java:‌​58) –
```

Comment: try to not hide any exceptions by leaving the `catch` clause empty. Could you include a print or something in there?

Comment: please note that `@Mock` is missing on `lineIterator`. Also instead to verifying `print` with a new line, try to verify `println` without new line it is much less error prone and tell me if it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see 3 issues in your test:

1. You don't try to mock **the correct constructor**, indeed in the method `execute`, you create your `PrintWriter` with **only one argument** of type `File` while you try to mock **the constructor with 2 arguments** one of type `File` and the other one of type `String`.

*So the code should rather be:*

```
PowerMockito.whenNew(PrintWriter.class)
    .withArguments(IMAGE_FILE)
    .thenReturn(mockPrintWriter);
```

2. To be able to mock a constructor you need to prepare the class creating the instance which is `ProcessImageData` in this case, so you need to add `ProcessImageData.class` in the annotation `@PrepareForTest`. (I'm not sure `ProcessImageDataTest.class` is needed there)
3. The field `lineIterator` should be annotated with `@Mock`.
4. Instead of verifying `print` with a new line, you should verify directly `println` **without new line** it is much less error prone.

---

I simplified your code to show the idea.

*Assuming that `ProcessImageData` is:*

```
public class ProcessImageData {

    private final File newImageDataTextFile;

    public ProcessImageData(final File newImageDataTextFile) {
        this.newImageDataTextFile = newImageDataTextFile;
    }

    public void execute() throws Exception{
        try (PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(newImageDataTextFile)) {
            LineIterator inputFileIterator = FileUtils.lineIterator(
                newImageDataTextFile, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.displayName()
             );
            while (inputFileIterator.hasNext()) {
                writer.println(inputFileIterator.nextLine());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

*My unit test would then be:*

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({ProcessImageData.class, FileUtils.class})
public class ProcessImageDataTest {

    private File file = new File("imageFilePath");

    private ProcessImageData processImageData;
    @Mock
    private PrintWriter mockPrintWriter;
    @Mock
    private LineIterator lineIterator;

    @Before
    public void init() throws Exception {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

        processImageData = new ProcessImageData(file);
        PowerMockito.whenNew(PrintWriter.class)
            .withArguments(file)
            .thenReturn(mockPrintWriter);
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(FileUtils.class);
        PowerMockito.when(
            FileUtils.lineIterator(file, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.displayName())
        ).thenReturn(lineIterator);
        PowerMockito.when(lineIterator.hasNext()).thenReturn(true, true, false);
    }

    @Test
    public void testExecute() throws Exception {
        PowerMockito.when(lineIterator.nextLine()).thenReturn("Foo", "Bar");
        processImageData.execute();
        Mockito.verify(mockPrintWriter,  Mockito.times(1)).println("Foo");
        Mockito.verify(mockPrintWriter,  Mockito.times(1)).println("Bar");
    }
}
```

For more details please refer to [**How to mock construction of new objects**](https://github.com/jayway/powermock/wiki/mockitousage#how-to-mock-construction-of-new-objects).

---

> how can I add verification in unit test for writer.close?

One way could be to simply check that `close()` at be called once by adding the next line to your unit test:

```
Mockito.verify(mockPrintWriter,  Mockito.times(1)).close();
```

Comment: Hey thanks. This worked. But it shows another error: 
Wanted but not invoked:
mockPrintWriter.print("ASIN2    url1
");
-> at softlines.ctl.ruleExecutor.tasks.ProcessImageDataTest.verify(ProcessImageDataTest.java:153)

However, there were other interactions with this mock:
-> at softlines.ctl.ruleExecutor.tasks.ProcessImageData.execute(ProcessImageData.java:51)
-> at softlines.ctl.ruleExecutor.tasks.ProcessImageData.execute(ProcessImageData.java:51)
-> at softlines.ctl.ruleExecutor.tasks.ProcessImageData.execute(ProcessImageData.java:58)

Comment: I have updated the question. can you tell why a specific mock interaction is not getting invoked.

Comment: Done!! Just one more thing. Where can I close the Print writer in the ProcessImageDataTest code??

Comment: Or it will be closed automatically, when execute() func is executed, and when finally block is run, at line 63 in the code?

Comment: yes you have no need to `close()` your writer in your test as it is already done in the method `execute()`

Comment: Thanks a lot! Just one more thing, how can I add verification in unit test for writer.close??

Answer (score 0):

Your construction of the PrintWriter doesn't match the mock. You told PowerMockito to return your mock like this:

```
PowerMockito.whenNew(PrintWriter.class).withArguments(IMAGE_FILE , StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name()).thenReturn(mockPrintWriter);
```

So you would have to say:

```
new PrintWriter(IMAGE_FILE, "UTF-8"); // 2 arguments
```

But instead in your `execute` method in the code that is being tested, you do:

```
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(newImageDataTextFile); // only 1 argument
```

So you either need to change the PowerMockito `withArguments` clause, or you need to add `"UTF-8"` to the constructor invocation in the `execute` method.